# How do I disable the device back button on Android (react-native)?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

How can I disable the physical device back button on Android with React-Native? I don't want to enable it for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current open screen is tracked with a listener created when the application is launched, in app.js. Main component of the app creates a BackHandler listener, which responds to the device back button according to the currently open screen.

Main component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress);
}

onBackPress = () => {
  if (this.props.currentScreen.name === 'app.main') {
     Alert.alert(
       'Confirm exit',
       'Do you want to exit App?',
       [
         {text: 'CANCEL', style: 'cancel'},
         {text: 'OK', onPress: () => {
           BackHandler.exitApp()
          }
        }
       ]
    );
  } else {
    Navigation.pop(this.props.currentScreen.id);
  }

  return true;
}
```

App.js

```
//register to compomentDidApperaListener to keep track on which screen is currently open. The componentName and Id are stored in my redux store
Navigation.events().registerComponentDidAppearListener(({ componentId, componentName }) => {
  store.dispatch(updateCurrentScreen({'name': componentName, 'id': componentId}))
})
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no out of the box support from React Native Navigation as of today on v2. However, you could use `BackHandler` from React native itself. To handle it and return false to disable it.

Doc on [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler)

#### Example

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In activity you can override the `onBackPressed()` and comment the calling to super class.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  // super.onBackPressed(); comment this line to disable back button  press
}
```

Comment: Sorry, seems like I didn't clearly specify that this was for react-native, and I am using a library called react-native-navigation for navigation